# Using Geometry Nodes, how would I build a procedural surface texture?

Tags: modeling, geometry-nodes

I want to wrap a base shape with a pattern of smaller objects, which will either extrude from or bool (difference) the surface. Below are some real world examples of the kind of objects I want to create.

I would love to know some methods for how to achieve this.  I know there are many ways to skin a cat, so I'm very keen to learn some different approaches.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Take a look at Tissue addon which comes by default with blender

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion @retr0, seems great for organic textures but I'm looking for more geometric/procedural. Cheers.